# What is known about Grothendieck's capacity of work?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, grothendieck

A lot has been said about Grothendieck's capacity of work, but what we know?

> (with references if possible) how was the work-day of Grothendieck, how many hours to day, what about his sleep?
>
> What is know about Grothendieck's habits of work (in manage routines, on time management)?

I'm specially interested in the "active" years (50's, 60's)

Comment: [link] (http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Grothendieck.html)

Comment: @AnishAbraham there doesn't appear to be much sufficiently specific information in that article to say anything concrete about e.g working hours.

Answer (score 6):

**"At the time, he had the capacity to be able to sleep when he wanted to, and for the number of hours he wanted to, in order to take up his work all the better afterward. In fact this capacity for work was to me something miraculous."** Memories of Schourik, Poénaru.

**"Schwartz came to realize that Grothendieck seemed to function on a biological schedule of 26 or 27 hours, which led him periodically to live on the opposite schedule from everyone else."** Mathematics III, Schneps and Scharlau